# What can I do with multi-subfigure figures on ResearchGate.net

Tags: graphics, online-publication, website, online-resource

As many of us are aware, ResearchGate.net is a popular site on which researchers showcase their publications. In addition to the PDF for a published work, the site interface allows you to upload PDFs for figures, together with captions.

This becomes difficult, however, when your figures are actually made up of multiple subfigures. There doesn't seem to be direct support for specifying subfigures of the same figures and having them show up alongside each other.

What (if anything) can be done to overcome this - other than uploading each subfigure separately, or not uploading them at all?

Comment: Could you upload a PDF containing all panels of the figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer, hinted at by @Anyon's comment, is to generate, for each figure, a PDF with the subfigures laid out as they are in the full work - and upload that. Perhaps one also needs to include the subfigure captions in that PDF.

This seems like a lot of hassle, but perhaps one can make LaTeX automate this somehow.